# No funciona print str()

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Estoy simulando una lista de espera en python, pero el print str no funciona, me guié a través de una fuente y vi que usaba print str, pero al ejecutarlo me salta un error ahí, adjunto el código, de antemano gracias a la comunidad.

```
import random

def simulacion ():
    i = 0
    Clientes = []
    TLL =[]
    TE = []
    TSER = []
    TOCIO = []
    TSAL = []
    NUM_CLIENTES = 100
    while(i<NUM_CLIENTES):
        if(i==0):
            Clientes.append(i)
            TLL.append(i)
            TE.append(i)
            TSER.append(random.random())
            TOCIO.append(i)
            TSAL.append(TLL[i]+TE[i]+TSER[i])
        if(i>=1):
            Clientes.append(i)
            TLL.append(TLL[i-1]+random.random())
            TE.append(max(TSAL[i-1],TLL[i])-TLL[i])
            TSER.append(random.random())
            TOCIO.append(max(TSAL[i-1],TLL[i])-TSAL[i-1])
            TSAL.append(TLL[i]+TE[i]+TSER[i])
        i = i + 1
    i = 0
    while(i<NUM_CLIENTES):
        print str(Clientes[i]) + ";" + str(TLL[i]) + ";" +str (TE[i]) + ";" +str(TSER[i]) + ";" + str(TSAL[i])
        i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso ocurre porque la sintaxis de `print()` lleva parentesis. CREO que lo que deberías hacer es: `print(str())`

Comment: Gracias, fue eso, y que lo estaba ejecutando desde Spyder y debía ejecutarlo desde la consola! muchas gracias!

Comment: No hay por qué!

Comment: Por favor, expande tu respuesta para explicar las diferencias entre Python 2.7 y 3.x. Tambièn seria bueno al menos listar todas las posibilidades de impresiòn (f-string, %, etc)